# How to find out who committed a certain file in Subversion?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How to find out who committed a certain file in Subversion? Or how to export the Actions from the log in TortoiseSVN? I don't have admin rights. In Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use something like below:

```
svn log -v http://server/repo  | grep --regexp="A .*filename" -B 2
```

Or, in TortoiseSVN, go to `Show Log` -> Click on `Show All` button. In the search box enter the filename you want ( or if you had right clicked on the file itself, hence showing only its log, you need not do this.) Now highlight all of them and copy and paste into a text editor and search in the editor using a regexp like maybe `Added : .*filename`

Answer (score 1):

Show Log should give you the info you need, as you can see when the commit was made; but if that doesn't work for some reason, perhaps 'blame' might give you a back door ?

But normally, just right click -> Tortoise SVN -> Show Log should work.

Last minute thought, click -> Tortoise SVN -> Properties and check the ... owner tag (from memory don't have SVN on my Dads Mac!)

Comment: I have to double click on each commit to see the Actions. I want to do a query if I have hundreds of commits over a long period of time or if I can export all the actions from these commits I can do a text search in the exported file.

Comment: I'll have to confirm this tomorrow when I'm back at my Workstation but I was pretty sure that show-log shows all the commits and if there's too much data, then you can limit the range of revisions to scan.

Answer (score 0):

`svn log -v` (may require installing a proper shell)